# use string for select statement in database pdo php

Tags: php, pdo, echo

This is just a thought i have for my project is it possible to use a string for example an `echo` as parameter for select statement in database query?
here is the scenario:

For example when my page loads i automatically display the latest data in database say last five entry, as echo of course. and for each entry there are other details and in order to view those other details i will have an anchor for each echo and i will direct the user to another page..using the echo i want to query the database for other details..

1. Is this possible?
2. I know I cant put attribute name to echo so how is this possible?
3. Any suggestions?

`Update`
this is the page that will show the echo

```
<form method="POST" action="crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                    <div class="headerimage"><img src="images/events.png"/></div>
                        <?php
                        foreach (LoadEvent() as $value){
                            echo '<div id="upcomingevent">';
                            //echo "<a href=\"#\" >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
                            echo "<a href='#' id=\"searchresultwhat\">".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"eventwhatcontent\" value=".$value['searchresultwhat'].">";
                            echo "<br/>\n";
                            echo $value['searchresultwhen'];
                            echo "<br/>\n";
                            echo $value['searchresultwhere'];
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </form>
```

then this is the method and the page where i must display the details of the event

```
<form method="POST" action="crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <?php
            echo '<div id="middlecontentupcomingevents">';
                LoadSpecificEvent();
                    echo '<div id="upcomingeventcontentimage">';
                    echo "<img src=\"admin/".$events[4]."\">";
                    echo $events[0];
                    echo $events[1];
                    echo $events[2];
                    echo $events[3];
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo "<br/>\n";
                    echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';  
        ?>
    </form>




function LoadSpecificEvent(){

    global $dbh;
    //var_dump($dbh);
    if (isset($_POST['eventwhatcontent'])) {
        $eventwhat = $_POST['eventwhatcontent'];
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_what = ?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$eventwhat);
        $stmt->execute();
        $events = array();
        $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $events[] = array(
                'searchresultwhat'  => $selected_row['event_what'],
                'searchresultwhere' => $selected_row['event_where'],
                'searchresultwhen'  => $selected_row['event_when'],
                'searchresultwho'   => $selected_row['event_who'],
                'searchresultimg'   => $selected_row['img_url']
            );
            print_r ($events);
        return $events;
    }
```

}

Comment: Don't think of strings and `echo` as being bound in any way - `echo` is a method for sending a string to _output_, but strings may be passed around internally using variables.  In any case, yes it is possible to pass strings into SELECT statements, though via PDO it is often not desirable to do so (instead being preferable to use `bindParam()` for injection-safe parameters). Please post your code and we can offer concrete suggestions.

Comment: ok sir i will post it please wait for update

Comment: You could pass some variables to the page as part of the URL (or turn it into a form and use POST instead if more complicated) - e.g. http://www.somesite.com/details.php?table=the_table_you_want etc. Then process these variables by first accessing them using `$_GET['table']` and check them for expected values using, for example, PHP's `filter_var()` method. Then use `bindParam()` to add to your PDO statement and away you go.

Comment: @adey_888 is i will use POST i need `name` right?since im using `echo` which has `no name` how can i get the `value` of the `parameter`?

Comment: You'd need to code it into your `POST` form as a hidden field e.g. in your code `echo "<input type='hidden' name='table' value='$the_table_you_want'>";`. I think a form might be overkill and putting the info in the URL will be fine. You might want to use AJAX and load the page output into a `<div>` on the first page if you don't want the URL to change/get ugly.

Comment: @adey_888 actually im using ajax to load pages and the reason why i dont use input is to avoid the ugly look...i will try to use this kind of approach i havent tried it so i might fail to achieve what i want be back on you on this one

Comment: You'll then be able to access this on the page _crud.php_ using `$_POST['table']` or `$_POST['searchwhat']` or whatever you decide to call the variable.

Comment: If you want to use a form with AJAX then you'll probably need to use something like `onSubmit="yourAJAXfunction(); return false;"`

Comment: i will try to do this please look at this post for update if i made..i may ask for suggestion if i wont make it thank you

Comment: @adey_888 i tried your approach i put the hidden input then put a name to it but i always get undefined index do you think it has something to do with the hidden type?maybe it is undefined because it is hidden?

Comment: Can you update the form HTML in your question and also provide the lines of the code in the page that is being called by the AJAX request? They name of the form input matches what is being asked for in the page that is called, right? You can use `if(isset($_POST['searchwhat'])) $searchwhat = $_POST['searchwhat'];` to check that POST variable is set/defined.

Comment: also, look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php - it returns _FALSE if the filter fails, or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set_

Comment: @adey_888 i did the isset now it is not defined will be back on you for next update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60426/discussion-between-adey-888-and-i-i).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski how would you use the echo to query the database?

Comment: @I--I It still is not clear what string or value from the output (echo) you want to use in a later query and where that query will occur. You can construct any HTML output you want, with any attributes needed using `echo`, and as long as that is valid HTML.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i have stated in the code above when page load it will query then display last 5 entry in database it will be displayed as echo then each of those 5 echo has an anchor which direct to another page where i want to display the other details for each entry now im using the echo as parameter to get other details in database i hope i am clear with this now